# Drive Wordpress through external RSS

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, syndication

Is there any way to add RSS feeds to Wordpress itself, and have Wordpress merge your posts with the ones from the RSS feed and display them as if they were posts on the blog itself?

More importantly, the external feeds must be present in the final RSS feed provided by Wordpress.

Ideally, I would like to setup a category in Wordpress, define a URL, and have that category driven by the external RSS feed.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better over @ http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://feedwordpress.radgeek.com/ ? Or http://devthought.com/projects/wordpress/wp-o-matic-the-wordpress-rss-agreggator/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of options: [FeedWordPress | simple and flexible Atom/RSS syndication for WordPress](http://feedwordpress.radgeek.com/) and [WordPress › SimplePie Plugin for WordPress « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simplepie-plugin-for-wordpress/) and [Developer's Guide - Google AJAX Feed API - Google Code](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxfeeds/documentation/) and [Magpie RSS - PHP RSS Parser](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial i wrote for this exact thing on one of my project : http://www.script-tutorials.com/importing-multiple-rss-feeds-using-newswidget-jquery/
Mainly its a multiple site's rss mixer/combiner. and it can be used as your idea by adding your site's rss in it as well. you can display post excerpts order by date of publishing etc.